# Difference between errorContainer and errorLabelContainer options in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using [`ErrorLabelContainer`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorlabelcontainer) I can display all the errors on my page in a single `div`.

What is the use of `errorContainer`?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Please refer to official documentation where all this is clearly explained](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer).

> **`errorLabelContainer`** - All error labels are displayed inside an
>   unordered list with the ID “messageBox”, **as specified by the
>   selector passed as `errorContainer`
>   option**.

In other words, as an example, the `errorLabelContainer` contains the errors as an unordered list.  This unordered list goes *inside* of the `errorContainer`.

Example usage:

```
$('form').validate({
    errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
    wrapper: "li"
});
```

Will yield this markup...

```
<div id="messageBox1">                 <!- errorContainer ->
    <ul>                               <!- errorLabelContainer ->
        <li>Field is required</li>     <!- wrapper ->
        <li>Enter a valid email</li>   <!- wrapper ->
    </ul>
</div>
```

To play around with how this works, you could create a jsFiddle demo and inspect the DOM to see how the rendered HTML is constructed.

Comment: If i will remove errorContainer: "#messageBox1" from above code .. it will give me same output .. then what is the use of adding errorContainer ??

Comment: @user2961938, Nobody said `errorContainer` was _mandatory_ and the "use of adding" this option is clearly demonstrated above.  I don't know what else to tell you.  As far as _your output_, that's a mystery since you haven't shown any code in your OP.

Comment: Thanks @sparky i m new to jquery and jquery validation and i was reading documentation .. and not able to differnciate between those two .. btw your code helped as well as this  http://jsfiddle.net/yashZ/yZdDE/1/

Comment: I have one more question can we display list of errors just after the controls as well as in #messagebox1 too  ??

Comment: @user2961938, You manually place an empty `#messagebox1` where-ever you want.